# How can I make vfill to work without adding any text before?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

Using `\vfill` between two texts works:

```
\newpage
bla
\vfill
blabla
```

but it doesn't work if there is no text before it:

```
\newpage
\vfill
blabla
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Adding an empty box like `\mbox{}` or `\hbox{}` (or `\null` for short) before the `\vfill` makes it work.

```
\newpage
\null
\vfill
blabla
```

Comment: remember that any box will add a blank line, so if the exact height of the fill is important, that must be taken into consideration.  a plain-tex alternative to a box is `\hrule height0pt depth0pt width1pc`; this puts something "solid" in place to anchor the `\vfill` but doesn't take up any measurable vertical space.

Comment: @barbara: Thanks, I actually thought about the introduced height while writing the post and thought to maybe replace `\null` with `\vspace*{0pt}`, but didn't wanted to mention it without testing it. Personally I actually like Andrew's suggestion to use `\vspace*{\fill}` better than my answer.

Comment: \hbox{}
\null
\vfill
did the job for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivo: `\null` is the same as `\hbox{}`, so one of the two is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I've tried all combinations, but for some reason it only worked with both. Maybe there's something wrong with my template - I don't know...

Answer (score 23):

LaTeX provides the macro `\vspace` for adding an amount of space, `\vspace{\fill}` has the same effect as `\vfill`, and has the same failing.  LaTeX *also* provides<sup>1</sup> the macro `\vspace*` for "I really, really do want you to put the space in here." so `\vspace*{\fill}` works.  That is to say,

```
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}%
blabla
```

puts the `blabla` at the bottom.

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `\vspace` and `\vspace*` are the same macro, but it's a convenient lie to think of them as variant macros.

Answer (score 10):

It's important to understand how TeX's page break mechanism works, at least for the main aspects.

When TeX decides where to break a page, it pushes back to the "list of recent contributions" what doesn't fit in the page and does the break.

Usually what doesn't fit are the final lines of a paragraph, but a break can very well happen at a vertical space (such breaks happen *always* before the vertical space). Now the break is performed and the vertical space is put back to be reconsidered; but nobody wants to start a normal page with a vertical space, so TeX makes it disappear.

This unless this vertical space is declared with `\vspace*`: this kind of vertical space is *never* considered for a break, it's just like a big invisibile character.

How the page break was chosen is irrelevant: this happens even at the start of a document. If you say

```
\begin{document}
\vspace{3cm}
```

this vertical space will not appear.

Using `\null` after `\newpage` effectively avoids the disappearance of vertical spaces, because `\null` puts on the page an empty box *before* the `\vspace` (something like a zero width and height character).

Thus the "good" way to build a dedication page, for instance, is

```
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{flushleft}
\itshape Dedicated to the people on \TeX.SX\\
         on the occasion of the first birthday\\
         of that wonderful site
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{\stretch{2}}
\cleardoublepage
```

The `\vspace*{\stretch{1}}` is actually equivalent to `\null\vfill`; but specifying the stretching with `\stretch` allows for nice effects: here the white space after the dedication is twice as much as the space before it.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is a non-breaking space. Just put it at the top of the page:

```
\newpage
~\vfill
blabla
```